# Batch Locate Folder

Tags: batch-file

Hello StackOverflow Community,

I am having trouble with batch, I want to make a Bat File. That can find the Folder of a game. Without specifying which Drive the folder is in. So Run the bat, and the bat moves files to this Folder. Even if the folder is in D Drive or C Drive.I am Currently doing in manually, by using IF EXIST and then Else. But that would only work for Two Drives.

I tried this

```
@echo off

for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
xcopy /Y /H "config\config.cfg" "%%d:\CSGO\cfg\"
)

@pause
```

Is there a way to perform this action?

Best Regards,
James

Comment: It would help if you were to restrict your search to a more specific location, i.e. `\Steam\steamapps\common\Counter-Strike Global Offensive\csgo\cfg\config.cfg` and what exactly is the problem with using an `If Exist` structure?

Comment: Is there a way to do this better? Right now it keeps creating a new folder in every selected driver. Is there a way i can xcopy a file to that destination if the folder path exists?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of attempting your copy within the loop, attempt a CD & redirect any *doesn't exist* errors to nul and GOTO to break out of the loop once you get a hit. Then you can perform your xcopy x:\config\config.cfg without a target from within your target destination.

```
for %%d in (c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
    cd /d "%%d:\CSGO\cfg" 2>nul && goto :FOUND
)

:FOUND
pause
```